# How to print the content of the last saved text file in a folder using Python

Tags: python

I want to print the content of the last saved text file in a folder using Python. I wrote the below code. It is printing out only the path of the file but not the content.

```
    folder_path = r'C:\Users\Siciid\Desktop\restaurant\bill'
    file_type = r'\*txt'
    files = glob.glob(folder_path + file_type)
    max_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)
    filename=tempfile.mktemp('.txt')
    open(filename,'w').write(max_file)
    os.startfile(filename,"print")
```

Is it possible to do this in Python. Any suggestion. I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the following code. Just replace the line where you open and write a file with these two lines:

```py
with open(max_file, "r") as f, open(filename, 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(f.read())
```

The max_file variable contains a file name, not the contents of the file, so writing it to the temp file and printing that will simply print the file name instead of its contents. To put its contents into the temporary file, you need to open the file and then read it. That is what the above two lines of code do.